# Scala/slick: Get the id of row inserted if not exists already

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to insert-if-not-exists already using this piece of code

```
case class Item(name: String, id: Long = 0L) // name is unique

val data = Query("Bob")
val exists = items.filter(_.name === "Bob").exists
val sel = data.filterNot(_ => exists)
val action = items.map(_.name).forceInsertQuery(sel)
```

It works but I want to return the id of the row (existing / inserted). Currently it returns a boolean. How do I get the id without having to query again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is `primary key` and `auto increment` then you can return the `id` in the same insert query. if not, its not possible.

```
val tableQuery = TableQuery[Items] //items is a slick table

def getIdAfterInsert(item: Item): DB[Long] = {
  tableQuery.filter(_.name === item.name).take(1).result.headOption.flatMap {
    case Some(dbItem) =>
      DBIO.successful(dbItem.id)
    case None =>
     tableQuery.returning(tableQuery.map(_.id)) += item 
  }
}
```

But if `id` is not `primary key` and `auto increment` then you have to do.

```
def getIdAfterInsert(item: Item): DBIO[Long] = {
 tableQuery.filter(_.name === item.name).take(1).result.headOption {
  case Some(item) => DBIO.successful(item.id)
  case None => 
    (tableQuery += item).flatMap { _ => 
      tableQuery.filter(_.name === item.name).take(1).result.id //this is the extra query
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: id is the primary key.. is it possible to return the existing row's ID instead of -1 ?

Comment: @srvy existing id `item.id` may not be the database id

Comment: @srvy changed the implementation just check